# changing format of invoice email

Tags: email, invoice

How to add logo in invoice and how to do formatting of Invoice if i want to add come text in invoice last how to add....?

1. I have to remove 'Your Invoice #100000047 Dt. for Order #100000185 Dt. (e.g:  18/08/2014)' Dt from invoice.
2. I have to add text at the last of invoice like Warranty?
3. Add amount in words..?

How can i do these changes in invoice sent on email...

Comment: which is final changed  text??

Comment: i need to do some minor changes like remove Dt from invoice number and add text at last of invoice...and adding logo in invoice email...

Answer (score 3):

You can find the invoice e-mail template in `app/locale/{lang_ISO}/template/email/sales/`.
There are 4 email template for invoices. All of them start with `invoice_`.
Either change them to what you need, or go to `System->Transactional emails` and create new e-mail templates based on the original templates.

Then you must go to `System->Configuration->Sales Emails->Invoice` and select as templates the e-mails you created.

Comment: thank u for information i have changed logo of invoice email by giving path in template i have created but it is not showing..

Comment: what's not showing?

Comment: my logo is headsets so it is showing the text only not showing logo...

Comment: check if the logo really exists.

Comment: Yes it is in the folder /webroot/media/email/logo/default

Comment: I think this is the subject for an other question. In your original question you asked HOW you can change the e-mail template. The answers provided in here show you exactly that. Accept one of the answers in here (both are equally valid) and ask an other question where you should explain what you did, show some code if possible and maybe you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales

There are 2 invoice email Template:

1) invoice_new

2) invoice_new_guest

or

Other method is

1) System->Transaction Email-> create your new Template

2) load invoice_new Temaplate
 Do the changes you want.

Comment: Thank you it did worked but i have given path of logo in the format but it is not coming up in invoice...

Comment: another correct way to do that is to go in BackEnd to System>>Configuration>>Design>>Transactional Emails>>Logo Image and easily pick your logo image from there.

Comment: Other option : {{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}